# Changing existing Core Data Image Store from Transformable to Binary Data/Allows External Storage

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, migration, binary-data

I am about to undertake the daunting project of converting my live (i.e. already on the app store for a number of years) app from Transformable to Binary Data store for images in Core Data.

I have many users with very large databases that store lots of images. This has really slowed down the Backup/Restore process, and probably caused some other behind-the-scenes issues as well. I didn't know any better when I set it up this way years ago.

How can I undergo this process so as not to lose even one of my customer's images? If it were just me and my own data, I'm sure I could get things working. But I want to be sure to do this properly, step by step, and I knew that this community could be a big help in that area. I really don't know where to start for the existing images.

Basically, I am looking for 1) steps to take, so as not to miss a beat. and 2) general advice, warnings, etc. in this process. I really need a clean migration when this version goes live.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

Comment: If you are not familiar with iCloud and Core Data synching then best spend 6 months getting familiar with it before you publish an App.  There are many edge cases you need to consider, especially if you are also considering using external images and keeping them in sync with your Core Data database.  Take a look at these sample App as a start and make sure you implement robust data backup and recovery options for your users.
http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/sample-library-style-ios-core-data-app-with-icloud-integration/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transformable data type is really just binary under the covers with some additional metadata.  Have you tested a simple lightweight migration on an existing store?  I suspect the migration would work and would leave the existing data in the store.

If you are looking to get the existing binary data actually moved out of the SQLite file then you are looking at something a bit more involved.

A heavy migration will accomplish what you are looking for but if the stores are large it may take took long and potentially not provide enough feedback for a good user experience.  I personally do not use heavy migrations, ever, on IOS but it will accomplish your goal.

An export/import will also work.  I generally recommend export/import when a lightweight migration won't work.  It involves a medium amount of code but in the end you own the code, understand the entire process and can tweak it to your exact needs.

Comment: From the answer of Z S above, it seems like I will need to move to managing all of the files myself since I am trying to implement Core Data iCloud sync as well. Ugh. What can of worms will this open? Is it even possible to get the "original" images back from the existing data, and if so, will this take even longer than the heavy migration you described above?

Comment: Heavy migration is the worst.  Doing an export/import will be faster (not as fast as lightweight migration) and will allow you to preserve all of the existing images because you will be exporting them out to disk as part of the migration.

Comment: Thanks Marcus. Do you think I would need to import, or just do the export if I am going to move the images into their own files and store the urls? Also do you recommend ensembles for Core Data/iCloud syncing, or is there really no stable solution yet and I should wait? Not trying to change the subject here, but it seems that the syncing strategy will ultimately affect the image storage strategy.

Comment: I do not use iCloud, it is not ready. My recommendation is you export out your data to JSON/images and the import it back into the new Core Data model with the images staying external.

Comment: Would you say that iCloud is now ready? I need to implement a syncing strategy and I have no idea which is the best way to go.

Comment: That is a complicated question because everyone has a different definition of what syncing is.  Does iCloud sync work? Yes. But do you need it?  Do you access a server?  If so, why not use the server as the source of truth instead of iCloud.  Will you ever go to another device?  If so, iCloud won't follow you.

Answer (score 3):

One piece of advice: don't use "Allows External Storage", especially if you plan to use iCloud syncing with Core Data in the future. Reference: http://www.objc.io/issue-10/icloud-core-data.html

Instead, you might want to consider moving the images into their own files, and saving the URL to those files inside your database instead. You will have to work out how best to do the migration: lightweight migration is probably not an option if you go down this route.

Comment: That's funny you should say that, I am starting to implement Core Data iCloud syncing today as well. The article was VERY eye opening. Doesn't inspire much confidence, especially the last part. So it seems that I have no choice but to save the URL, right? Or maybe it is still not "the time" to try to implement sync yet? I am looking at Drew McCormack's ensembles, if you have any thoughts on that.

Comment: My personal opinion (after having shipped iCloud Core Data sync in my app) is that it's pretty solid if you limit yourself to iOS7 / 10.9 ONLY. No question that you shouldn't support anything before that. Even then, it requires some work to support, like that article mentions (options to switch iCloud on/off, account transitions etc); the most common situation to run into is that the sync stops working after a while for some users and you have to provide a way to reset the container. I would do more research.

Comment: I haven't looked enough into Ensembles to comment on it's abilities, but I'd be wary of trusting another individual's implementation vs. Apple's. Apple's version has had problems since shipping, but they've improved it substantially in every update, and they have a team of people supporting this going forward. It's important to know who you are building dependancies against. But you should do your own research obviously.

Comment: Can someone please update this? It's been more than a year since these comments were made. I've read the article too but it's iOS 9 round the corner and I suspect 'Allow External Storage' would (read: should) work? If not, we'd have heard of more screams and complaints. I'm about to create a new project and need to make the right decisions. Thanks!